# Connect to Azure Storage Queue Behind Proxy

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, http-proxy, azure-storage-queues

I have a .NET Core 2.2 Console app to connect to an Azure Storage Queue. It works on my computer, but I can't get it to work behind a corporate proxy. What do I need to do? (I anonymized the storage account name and key and the proxy hostname.)

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue" Version="10.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

Wrapper class:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Queue
{
    public class Queue
    {
        public Queue(string connectionString, string queueName)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);            
            var cloudQueueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            CloudQueue = cloudQueueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);            
        }

        private CloudQueue CloudQueue { get; }

        public async Task<string> PeekAsync()
        {
            var m = await CloudQueue.PeekMessageAsync();            
            return m.AsString;
        }
    }
}
```

AppSettings.json

```
{
  "StorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=someAccount;AccountKey=someKey==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy 
        usesystemdefault="True" 
        proxyaddress="http://someProxy:8080" 
      />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to set the proxy in `App.config` because it is not handled. This is only valid for classic .NET. You need to set the proxy on each component. There is no global proxy setting (yet) in dotnet core. I faced the issue last week and found out that there is no proxy setting for `CloudStorageAccount`

Comment: It seems like it’s ignoring every possible proxy option I throw at it. Do I just use HttpClient/WebClient and call the REST APIs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found some hints on the official [azure-storage-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) repo:

Idea:

1. create a custom class that inherits from `DelegatingHandler` to set the proxy there
2. use that class in your application

Implementation based on your sample:

**DelegatingHandlerImpl.cs** (taken from https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Test/Common/TestBase.Common.cs)

```
public class DelegatingHandlerImpl : DelegatingHandler
{
    public int CallCount { get; private set; }

    private readonly IWebProxy Proxy;

    private bool FirstCall = true;

    public DelegatingHandlerImpl() : base()
    {

    }

    public DelegatingHandlerImpl(HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler) : base(httpMessageHandler)
    {

    }

    public DelegatingHandlerImpl(IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        this.Proxy = proxy;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CallCount++;
        if (FirstCall && this.Proxy != null)
        {
            HttpClientHandler inner = (HttpClientHandler)this.InnerHandler;
            inner.Proxy = this.Proxy;
        }
        FirstCall = false;
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Queue.cs**

```
public class Queue
{
    public Queue(string connectionString, string queueName)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var proxy = new WebProxy()
        {
            // More properties here
            Address = new Uri("your proxy"),
        };
        DelegatingHandlerImpl delegatingHandlerImpl = new DelegatingHandlerImpl(proxy);
        CloudQueueClient cloudQueueClient = new CloudQueueClient(storageAccount.QueueStorageUri, storageAccount.Credentials, delegatingHandlerImpl);
        CloudQueue = cloudQueueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
    }

    private CloudQueue CloudQueue { get; }

    public async Task<string> PeekAsync()
    {
        var m = await CloudQueue.PeekMessageAsync();
        return m.AsString;
    }
}
```

Successfully tested this when i am behind our proxy.

Sidenote: Delete your `App.config` setting for `defaultProxy` it is not used by dotnet core.

Comment: I see 2 overloads for the CloudQueueClient constructor:
`public CloudQueueClient(Uri baseUri, StorageCredentials credentials);`
`public CloudQueueClient(StorageUri storageUri, StorageCredentials credentials);`
and the example you gave accepts 3 arguments. I upgraded to Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue 10.0.2.

Comment: When I changed from the Microsift.WindowsAzure.Storage namespaces to the Microsift.Azure.Storage namespaces, that new constructor was there. It's the same NuGet package.

Comment: Error Innermost DelegatingHandler must have a null InnerHandler